# Quilljs setContents(json_string_with_escapes)

Tags: javascript, json, quill

I am trying to use the function setContent with QuillJS.

When i am saving the content using JSON.stringify to a database, it looks like this:

```
{"ops":[{"insert":"\n \n"},{"attributes":{"color":"#4572a7","bold":true},"insert":"#test 1"},{"attributes":{"color":"#000000"},"insert":": "},{"insert":"\n"}]}
```

When I return the string, echo json_encode from PHP produces a string with escapes like this:

```
[["{\"ops\":[{\"insert\":\"\n \n\"},{\"attributes\":{\"color\":\"#4572a7\",\"bold\":true},\"insert\":\"#test 1\"},{\"attributes\":{\"color\":\"#000000\"},\"insert\":\": \"},{\"insert\":\"\n\"}]}"]]
```

It seems like the quill.setContents function doesn't like that very much

```
quill.setContents(JSON.parse(content));

quill.setContents(content));
```

None of these methods works with a escaped string, what is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Quill need a valid JavaScript object or Delta.

json_encode encodes a PHP object into a JSON string. In your case you already have a JSON encoded string. Just send it to the browser, call JSON.parse(content) and pass it to quill.setContents()